# Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $A \subset B$. Show that $m^\ast(B) \le m^\ast(A)+\varepsilon.$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $A \subset B$. Show that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that  $m^\ast(B) \le m^\ast(A)+\varepsilon.$

Is there a mistake in the problem statement here? If $A \subset B$ then how can the outer measure of $A$ ever be greater than $B$? If $\mathcal{F}$ is a Lebesgue cover for $B$ then clearly $\mathcal{F}$ is a Lebesgue cover for $A$ so $$\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_i) \mid A\subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty I_i\} \subset\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_i) \mid B\subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty I_i\}$$ and so taking the infima $$m^\ast(A) \le m^\ast(B)?$$

Answer (score 0):

$B=\mathbb R^{n}, A=\emptyset$ gives  a counter-example.

But if $m^{*}(B)<\infty$  we can take $\epsilon =m^{*}(B)-m^{*}(A)+1$.